# Apache2 redirect not working properly

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-jessie

I have all my domains in a single vhosts.conf file that I have rsync across three servers. All three for some reason do not redirect `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` but will redirect `http://example.net` to `https://example.net`. Instead, `http://example.com` will just show the default page.

I have `rewrite`, `ssl`, `headers`, and `env` enabled as well. Apache was reloaded and also restarted. Debian 8 with Apache2. I removed the VirtualHost for port 443 (SSL) to shorten the conf file.

```
# example.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# example.net
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.net
        ServerAlias www.example.net
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net

        Redirect permanent / https://example.net/

        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.net_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.net_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

They do not redirect because the first virtualhost which does not have a server name is probably grabbing all requests.

Always define ServerName for each virtualhost.

Comment: Still not working, it just picks the next virtualhost section that's on top. Each one has a ServerName defined too.

Comment: This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had ServerAdmin spelled wrong on one of the virtual host blocks.